# How to distingiush between two tables?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables that looks very similar:

`Table A`:

```
table_c_id     address         country    status  defaultA   deafultB 
1               480 st          4          170     True      False
2               271 st          4          150     False     False
3              174 St post 44   3          150     False     False
```

And:

`Table B`:

```
table_b_id   address         country    isdefault  canoverwrite  linked
1                              12         True      False         33
48           Kyat St.          17                   True
155          Rover St          17                   True          14
```

basicly it's simply two tables that contains address, they are used for diffrent porupses (lets say one is `Customer` adress and the other is `Supllier` address)

I need to create a 3rd table and have forigenkey of address. My issue is that the forigenkey can be either from `table A` or `table B`.

say the schema is:

```
table_Cid , id , ......
```

id should be a FK to either Table_A or Table_B but it's not enough... I won't be able to know which one of the table it actualy refers.

say  one line is:

```
table_Cid , id , ......
 111         1
```

Which row `1` is? is it 1 of table_a or 1 of table_b?

How can I define `table_c` to handle this?
Assume that there can't be any change to `table_a` nor `table_b`.

Comment: I'd say have one common table for all addresses... Then you'll need only one FK - problem solved-

Comment: I wrote specificly that I can not change the stacture of table_A and table_B. I am aware of this approch i'm looking for something else

Comment: Then use trigger(s) that does the FK work for you, at INSERT/UPDATE and perhaps DELETE.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Problems like this indicates there could something wrong with the db design. That's what I tried to tell you with my first comment...

Comment: Either triggers. Or have separate C columns for table A fk's and table B fk's. You can have a C view that selects the valid one for each row.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a column call 'type' to distinguish the FK_ID from table_a or table_b. e.g: type:1(from table_a) the sql is: select * from table_c join table_a on fkId = table_a_id where type=1

Answer (score 0):

Store the foreign key references in separate columns, depending on if it's for table A or table B. Make sure that only one of them is set:

```
create table c (id integer,
                ...
                a_fk integer references A (id),
                b_fk integer references B (id),
                ...
                check (a_fk is null or b_fk is null))
```

Create a view that returns the current FK column, and also indicates if its to table A or table B:

```
create view cv as select id, ...
                         coalesce(a_fk, b_fk) as fk_val,
                         case when a_fk is not null then 'A'
                              when b_fk is not null then 'B'
                         end as fk_tbl,
                         ... 
                  from c
```